# Installing Ubuntu from an external HDD

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I have downloaded the latest Ubuntu iso. I want to install it as a dual boot on office laptop.
Unfortunately, I have no flash drive or a CD/DVD with me. I just have an enclosed internal HDD connected to my laptop via USB, which has the ISO in one of its drives. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is windows already installed on the laptop?  Do you need to resize the windows partition?  Check out [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=28948) for instructions.  There is a more updated explanation of [setting up the dual boot in Vista](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/14/how-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-linux/).

A totally different a [Wubi install](http://wubi-installer.org/).  Unfortunately, that means another download for you.  You install the wubi installer & it handles installing Ubuntu for you.  You don't have to dual boot and you can have Ubuntu running at the same time as Windows, no virtual machine.